# Primefaces 5 JSF 2.2 h:selectOneMenu populates child menu with wrong data

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a maven-hibernate-primefaces project with three nested h:selectOneMenu (Country -> City -> Address) as follow,

```
<h:outputLabel for="countryList" value="Countries" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="countryList" value="#{userBean.newCountry}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" >
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{userBean.selectedCountry}"
             itemLabel="#{userBean.selectedCountry.country}" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.countries}" var="country" 
             itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.country}"/>
  <f:ajax listener="#{userBean.loadCities}" render="cityList" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputLabel for="cityList" value="Cities" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="cityList" value="#{userBean.newCity}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" >
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select city" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.cities}" var="city"
             itemValue="#{city}" itemLabel="#{city.city}" />
  <f:ajax listener="#{userBean.loadAddresses}" render="addressList" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputLabel for="addressList" value="Address" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="addressList" value="#{userBean.newAddress}"  converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" >
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select address" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.addresses}" var="address"
             itemValue="#{address}" itemLabel="#{address.address} #{address.address2}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and from userBean I have the corresponding properties and methods as follow,

```
private Users newUser = new Users();
private Employees newEmployee = new Employees();
private Department newDepartment = new Department();
private Address newAddress = new Address();
private City newCity = new City();
private Country newCountry = new Country();
private Users selectedUser;
private Employees selectedEmployee;
private Department selectedDepartment;
private Address selectedAddress;
private City selectedCity;
private Country selectedCountry;
private List<Users> users = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Employees> employees = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

public void loadCities() {
    cities = CountryDAO.findCitiesOfCountry(sessionFactory, newCountry);
}

public void loadAddresses() {
    addresses = CityDAO.findAddressesOfCity(sessionFactory, newCity);
}

public void changeEmployee(SelectEvent event) {
    selectedEmployee = (Employees) event.getObject();
    selectedDepartment = EmployeeDAO.findDepartmentOfEmployee(sessionFactory, selectedEmployee);
    selectedAddress = EmployeeDAO.findAddressOfEmployee(sessionFactory, selectedEmployee);
    selectedCity = AddressDAO.findCityOfAddress(sessionFactory, selectedAddress);
    selectedCountry = CityDAO.findCountryOfCity(sessionFactory, selectedCity);
}
```

The method 'changeEmployee' select an employee from a row of an amployees datatable so I have created different calls until get a selected country to where he belongs

All of this is ok. The problem is with the selectOneMenu,

CountryDAO

```
public static List<City> findCitiesOfCountry(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Country country) {

    List<City> myCityList;

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    //start transaction
    session.beginTransaction();

    String hql = "from Country c join fetch c.cityList where c.countryId = :countryId";
    Country ctry = (Country) session.createQuery(hql)
                        .setShort("countryId", country.getCountryId())
                        .list().get(0);
    myCityList = ctry.getCityList();

    //Commit transaction
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();


    return myCityList;
}
```

CityDAO

```
public static List<Address> findAddressesOfCity(SessionFactory sessionFactory, City city) {

    List<Address> myAddressList;

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    //start transaction
    session.beginTransaction();

    String hql = "from City c join fetch c.addressList where c.cityId = :cityId";
    City cty = (City) session.createQuery(hql)
                        .setShort("cityId", city.getCityId())
                        .list().get(0);
    myAddressList = cty.getAddressList();

    //Commit transaction
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();

    return myAddressList;
}
```

Though the list are populate they come with wrong data.

Here you've got the hbm mapping files,

country.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.Country" table="country">
    <id name="countryId" type="java.lang.Short" column="COUNTRY_ID" >
        <generator class="native" />
    </id> 
    <property name="country" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="COUNTRY"/>
    </property>
    <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
      <column name="LAST_UPDATE"/>
    </property>
    <bag name="cityList" table="city"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="city_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.City" />
    </bag>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

city.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.City" table="city">
    <id name="cityId" type="java.lang.Short" column="CITY_ID" >
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="CITY"/>
    </property>
    <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
      <column name="LAST_UPDATE"/>
    </property>
    <bag name="addressList" table="address"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="ADDRESS_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.Address" />
    </bag>
    <many-to-one name="country" class="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.Country" fetch="select">
        <column name="COUNTRY_ID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

address.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.Address" table="address">
    <id name="addressId" type="java.lang.Short" column="ADDRESS_ID" >
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="ADDRESS"/>
    </property>
    <property name="address2" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="ADDRESS2"/>
    </property>
    <property name="district" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="DISTRICT"/>
    </property>
    <property name="postalCode" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="POSTAL_CODE"/>
    </property>
    <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="PHONE"/>
    </property>
    <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
      <column name="LAST_UPDATE"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="city" class="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.City" fetch="select">
        <column name="city_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <bag name="employeesList" table="EMPLOYEES"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.Employees" />
    </bag>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I execute the Primefaces page countries list is ok but following with the nested childs I am getting wrong data.

Witch is the problem? Where my code gets wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any primefaces components? Did you debug to know if the problem is in the facelet or the model? What is wrong data, addresses from another city?

Comment: Hi. When I say wrong data I am meaning the values in the child menu not correspond to the selected parent menu (in all cases).

Comment: Let me show you what glassfish shows when I deploy the webapp, `WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>>> from public void org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansRepository.setRequestScopedBeansViewId(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean<?>>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.` I think I have not the lists well built

Comment: It was a mistake of mine. I have done the code again and now works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Being the hibernate ORM right here is the method that select the content of every h:selectOneMenu,

```
@PostConstruct
public void initUsers() {
    HttpSession session = HttpSessionUtil.getSession(false);
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) session.getAttribute("sessionFactory");

    -------------------
    -------------------
    countries = CountryDAO.listCountries(sessionFactory);
}

public void loadCities() {
    cities = CityDAO.findCitiesOfCountry(sessionFactory, newCountry);
}

public void loadAddresses() {
    addresses = AddressDAO.findAddressesOfCity(sessionFactory, newCity);
}
```

I get the complete list of countries in the post construct method and later depending on every selected item I am going giving the content to the others selectOneMenu
and the Primefaces page leaves as follow,

```
<h:outputLabel for="countryList" value="Countries" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="countryList" value="#{userBean.newCountry}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{userBean.selectedCountry}" itemLabel="#{userBean.selectedCountry.country}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.countries}" var="country" 
                                   itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.country}"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{userBean.loadCities}" render="cityList" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputLabel for="cityList" value="Cities" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="cityList" value="#{userBean.newCity}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{userBean.selectedCity}" itemLabel="#{userBean.selectedCity.city}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.cities}" var="city"
                                   itemValue="#{city}" itemLabel="#{city.city}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{userBean.loadAddresses}" render="addressList" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputLabel for="addressList" value="Address" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="addressList" value="#{userBean.newAddress}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{userBean.selectedAddress}" itemLabel="#{userBean.selectedAddress.address}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.addresses}" var="address"
                                   itemValue="#{address}" itemLabel="#{address.address}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This way now it works fine. You can see the job at http://www.josealvarezdelara.com/HibernateWebApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ui/home.jsf where Jose Alvarez de Lara is me

Comment: The above link does not work because I have closed that site but you can see and download the whole webapp from GitHub at https://github.com/GGSvennson/jolly-roger. Thanks